# Same picture stored twice on sstatic.net

Tags: support, images, optimization, bandwidth

Currently any question on Programmers SE ([this for example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145669/what-software-programming-languages-were-used-by-the-soviet-unions-space-progra)) page source contains this in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/programmers/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
 [SKIPPED]
<link rel="image_src" href="http://sstatic.net/programmers/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

and looks like the same goes for any other Stack Exchange site except Meta.

For any given site the two images look completely identical and loading them twice from different URLs looks completely useless.

Two concerns:

1. why those are two distinct URLs instead of one URL
2. why these two links are present on pages with questions only, but the main page only contains the first link

Comment: First one is for Apple's devices, second one is for Facebook, neither is requested when visiting the site from your browser.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Why not store just one and use the same URL twice?

Comment: It is only stored once (the CDN just pulls from sstatic.net).

Comment: As @balpha said, it's only stored once. Apple and FB have different ways of locating the image, hence the redundancy. Welcome to web development!

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Why are two distinct URLs required?

Comment: I don't think they are. @balpha?

Comment: They're not required. They might as well use the same URL; they just happen to appear that way. *It just doesn't matter.*

Comment: @balpha: I've discovered that the links are different on the main page and on the questions pages and edited the question to reflect my findings. Is that okay?